# How to create a asynchronous waitbar in MATLAB for a parallel external process?

Tags: matlab

I need to wait for a process to finish with basically unknown duration. I call this process via:

```
output = system('foo.cmd')
```

Process `foo` is blocking any further execution of code. The process takes often about 10 seconds to finish and does not return any status but its output value afterwards. Sometimes it takes a second, sometimes a minute or more. To simulate the progress to the user I would like to implement a waitbar in advance of the excution, somehow like:

```
function f = my_waitbar()
    f = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');

    for i=1:10
    pause(1)
        waitbar(i/10,f,'Executing foo');
    end
    waitbar(1,f,'Finishing, please wait...'); % should wait now and do nothing
end
```

Then after `foo.cmd` finished I would close the bar.

```
f = my_waitbar() % blocks my code from execution, therefore is pointless
output = system('foo.cmd')
close(f)
```

But by just calling function `f = my_waitbar()` in advance, the process would not be triggered parallel. How do I execute `my_waitbar()` without waiting for it to be finished?

Note that everything after `system('foo.cmd')` is depending on its execution, therefore further code execution has to wait for it as it does now, so `system('foo.cmd &')` would not work well for me.

**EDIT**

Please assume that I have no influence on the content of `foo.cmd`

Comment: Do you have control over the process "foo.cmd" ? If you can make it create a file (even empty) when it is finished, then there are ways for MATLAB to monitor that without blocking the thread. Or turning the question around, does the process already create or delete any file while running ?

Comment: "foo.cmd" triggers an process not running on my device, and I have no control over it. 

It basically sends a previously created json to a custom webservice, and receives a json as answer when finished. No status in between (That's my issue). 

No files are created, I get a simple json with some values as `output` or an error mesage if something failed.

Comment: But `foo.cmd` is a script running on your computer. It could potentially be edited to write a file, as @Hoki suggests, so that your MATLAB process has something to look for.

Comment: This would just move my problem from MATLAB to the script. Please assume that I have no influence on the content of `foo.cmd`.

Comment: Do you really need an external script? Could you not send the request and receive the json directly in MATLAB?

Comment: In principle yes. Sure, the whole execution could be done in MATLAB. But that's not the point of the question. Thank you very much anyway for your answer! It points to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a great UX choice to have a percentage-based progress bar which may "complete" long before your process does, or never complete because your process finishes sooner. See [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21727/indeterminate-progress-indicator-styles) on UX.stackexchange which discusses the alternatives. In short, a spinner is more conventional.

You can create a custom load spinner fairly easily. This uses an [undocumented](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/displaying-animated-gifs) but simple method to display an animated gif within a figure without having to use code to advance the frames (which would not work for an asynchronous task!).

There are several options for animated gifs already shipped with MATLAB, I've chosen to use this one:

[image: loader]

Here is the code and the result (note that in reality the result is animated!)

```
function hFig = loadspinner()    
    % Main path for installed MATLAB images (and other files)
    fp = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab');
    % Path to the image we want, there are other options in this folder...
    fp = fullfile(fp, 'sourcecontrol\release\images\spinner.gif');

    % Create the figure    
    hFig = figure('Color', 'w', 'NumberTitle', 'Off', ...
                  'Resize', 'Off', 'Menubar', 'None');
    % Get image size to reduce hard-coding in case we change image
    sz = size( imread( fp ) );
    % Insert the animated gif into a HTML pane to enable the animation
    je = javax.swing.JEditorPane('text/html', ['<html><img src="file:/', fp, '"/></html>']);
    [~, hc] =  javacomponent(je,[],hFig);
    % resize figure and image
    hFig.Position(3:4) = [220,sz(2)+35];
    set(hc, 'pos', [(220-sz(1))/2-2,6,sz(1)+4,sz(2)+4])
    % Add text
   annotation( hFig, 'textbox', [0,0.9,1,0], ...
                'String', 'Loading, please wait...', ...  
                'LineStyle','none', ...
                'margin', 0, ...
                'verticalalignment', 'top', ...
                'horizontalalignment', 'center' );
end
```

[image: result]

You could use this the same as you showed for the `waitbar`

```
f = loadspinner();
output = system('foo.cmd')
close(f);
```

Comment: Nice trick. You could try it with that gif too: [loader.gif](https://i.imgur.com/z9YDEGe.gif)

Comment: @Hoki my original answer made the gif optional, that one is nice, as is a blue circle spinner (can't remember the name). I simplified the code before posting though!

Answer (score 3):

As Wolfie already mentionned, a standard progressbar is not suited to wait for a process with unknown duration (or unknown iterations). In these cases you better use a spinner (gif file), a circular waitbar (good choice on the File Exchange: [cProgress](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53383-cprogress)), or an *indefinite* progressbar. This is what I used for this example:

[image]

---

Now how to make it possible. Since I cannot replicate your exact process foo.cmd, I replaced it by the dos command `dir`. So for the base line example:

```
tic
command = 'dir' ;
[~,cmdout] = system(command) ;
toc

>> Elapsed time is 1.547987 seconds.
```

1.5 second is enough to notice, and `cmdout` does indeed contain the list of files and directories. So I'll assume this is as close as your case than can be.

To be able to monitor the end of the process, I will package the call to `dir` (or in your case the call to `foo.cmd`) into a batch file which will:

- Check if a file (`"MyProcessIsFinished"`) exist. If yes delete it.
- Call the process of interest, redirect the output to a file.
- Create an empty file `"MyProcessIsFinished"`

This allow MATLAB to call the batch file **without** waiting for the result (using `&`). You then make MATLAB wait until it detects the file. When detected, you know the process is finished, you can close your waitbar and continue execution of your code. You can then read the file containing the results you used to get in `cmdout`.

```
% initialise flag
processFinished = false ; 

% start the continuous waitbar
hw = mywaitbar(0.5,'Please wait','Waiting for response ...',true);

% call the process in the batch file, without waiting for result
command = 'mycommand.bat &' ;
system(command) ;

% wait for the process to be finished
while ~processFinished
    if exist('MyProcessIsFinished','file')
        processFinished = true ;
    end
end
close(hw) ; % close the wait bar

% now read your results
cmdout = fileread('outputfile.txt') ;
```

The file `mycommand.bat` is now:

```
@echo off
if exist MyProcessIsFinished del MyProcessIsFinished
dir > outputfile.txt
copy nul MyProcessIsFinished > nul
exit
```

Don't forget to replace the line `dir > outputfile.txt` by a call to your process and a redirection to a suitable file name. It could look like:

```
foo.cmd > ReceivedRequest.json
```

---

The continuous waitbar: I picked up `mywaitbar.m` from the file exchange: [mywaitbar](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46896-mywaitbar). The code is nice but I had to change a couple of things to improve the timer management so if you want a working version there will be a couple of changes:

- Line 109: Add `'CloseRequestFcn',@closeRequestFcn` to the properties of the new figure.
- Line 120: Add `'Name','CircularWaitbarTimer'` to the properties of the new timer

Then at the bottom of the file, add the following function:

```
function closeRequestFcn(hobj,~)
    % Delete the timer
    t = timerfindall('Name','CircularWaitbarTimer') ;
    if strcmpi('on',t.Running)
        stop(t) ;
    end
    delete(t)
    delete(hobj)
```

That will make a more stable waitbar utility and will get rid of the annoying warning/error messages about timers not managed properly.